# What's the difference between Get.to(page) and Get.to(() => page in Flutter GetX?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

Basically why the framework says that Get.to(() => page) is better than the other method? For me they are the same but I'd like to know if there's any difference or impact.

I'm using the Get.to(() => page) but only because the framework says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight difference between both.

1. `Get.to(page)` just uses default constructor to create new instance of the page. Meaning if your page has any dependencies, you would have to pass them as constructor arguments.
2. `Get.to(()=>page)` creates page lazily using a closure or `lambda` function.  As a result, you may build the page utilising GetX's dependencies by using the `Get.put()` or `Get.lazyPut()` methods.

To summarize

```
Get.to(MyPage()); // No dependency injection

Get.to(() => MyPage()); // Allows for dependency injection
```

Comment: Very thankful! It's clear for me now.